# Is null graph a subgraph of every graph?

Tags: graph-theory

My book says a subgraph is: "A graph G is a subgraph of graph H if the nodes of G are a subset of the nodes of H, and the edges of G are a subset of the edges of H" ( Theory of Computation, 3rd edition, page 11 )

I wonder if null graph is a subgraph of every graph because null graph = empty graph = empty sets for vertices and edges = phi and phi is a subset of every graph

Comment: Your reasoning seems to be valid :-)

Comment: Some authors insist that the set of vertices be nonempty. They then have the null graph with one vertex and no edges. Even with this restriction, the null graph is a subgraph of every graph.